# Pls help: encountered "input/output error" while trying to duplicate (medical) CD

Tags: external-disk, disk-image

I have a medical CD that needs to be duplicated (explanation below).

While trying to create a disc image, Disk Utility encountered an "input/output error". The complete message was "Operation failed with status 5: input/output error". The disk itself is fine.

System info: Mac OS Ventura, MacBook Pro M1 with an external drive.

- Reasons I need to figure this out: The medical centers cannot accept files via Google Drive link, download attached files, or a thumb drive. Requesting a duplicate copy is taking way longer than expected and we don't know how many needed).

Comment: Does the Cd have copy protection? or else it just has corrupted data.

Comment: I don't think it has copy protection--I can copy the files onto my computer. The files on that CD are all for PCs (not for Mac). Would that have made a difference?

Comment: If you can copy all the (needed) files onto your Mac I would be tempted to do just that. Put the files in a folder and then burn that folder to a CD using the contextual menu click (control-click) on that folder. That will give you a Mac Formatted CD, if you need something formatted for PCs and the like there is CD burning software available commercially and (likely) as shareware....

Comment: Thank you-will try that. Files on the medical CD (MRIs, CT Scans) seem to be using a special format. I thought maybe that was why the doctors' office wouldn't accept the thumb drive with all the files on it.